# How to call window.print on html page returned after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, printing

I have a print button inside a bootstrap modal.

```
$('#printST').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'print',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
           // how to print the content of html?
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to print the data returned.

In my print page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
```

In my controller

```
...
    return View::make('pages.print');
```

How can i print the content of this pages after ajax call?

Comment: well you need to add it to the page to print it.

Comment: @epascarello How can i return the html page in ajax call? The print() function is already there.

Comment: why are you not just opening it up in a new window? Loading a page with Ajax does nothing, it is plain text.

Comment: @epascarello i no want to show the page to be printed, and the page to be printed is just a normal table format.

Comment: I am saying, why use Ajax when you want to load something to print. Just open it up in a new window and it will print, no fancy code is needed. If you do it with Ajax, it requires you to append the code the the page, hook up a print stylesheet to only print the table, and print it.... That window print code in the page you are loading is not going to anything.

Comment: `window.open("print?" + yourForm.serialize())` or a hidden iframe....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling and returning `return View::make('pages.print');` will not help as it only create instance of `View` Class. you need `HTML` string and for that you need to call `render()`

so for you controller

```
 $view = View::make('pages.print'); 
 return $view->render();
```

it will return `HTML` string to Ajax function

In your Ajax call

```
$('#printST').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'print',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            w = window.open(window.location.href,"_blank");
            w.document.open();
            w.document.write(html);
            w.document.close();
            w.window.print();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

it will open `print window` for returned `HTML` from Controller

Hope this will help!